# why is my program displaying the array wrong?

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my program. When I compile and run my program everything runs great until it's time to display the guesses back to the user. when that happens the last guess always gets displayed as 0.

My assignment is to develop a program that simulates the high-low game. For each execution of the program, the game will generate a random number in the inclusive range of 1 to 100. The user will have up to 10 chances to guess the value. The program will keep track of all the user’s guesses in an array. For each guess, the program will tell the user if his/her guess was too high or too low. If the user is successful, the program will stop asking for guesses, display the list of guesses, and show a congratulatory message stating how many guesses he/she took. If the user does not guess the correct answer within 10 tries, the program will display the list of guesses and show him/her the correct value with a message stating that he/she was not successful. Regardless of the outcome, the program will give the user a chance to run the program again with a new random number.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author jose
*/
public class Assignment7
{

/*

*/
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int number;
  
   String again = "y";

   while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   {
      int[] guesses = new int[10];
      int tries = 0;
  
      number = GetRandomNumber(1, 100);
      System.out.println(number); // delete before submitting

      int userGuess = GetUserGuess(1,100);
  
      while (userGuess != number && tries < guesses.length - 1 )
      {
         guesses[tries] = userGuess;
         LowOrHigh(number, userGuess);
         userGuess = GetUserGuess(1, 100);
         tries++;
  
      }
  
      if (tries != 10)
      {
         userGuess = guesses[tries];
         tries++;
         System.out.println("Congratulations! You were able to guess the correct number");
      }
  
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Sorry! You were not able to guess the correct number");
      }


      if (tries == 10)
      {
         System.out.println("Your guesses were incorrect");
         System.out.print("You guessed: ");

         for ( int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
         {
            System.out.print(guesses[i] + ", ");
         }

            System.out.println("The random number generated was " + number);
         }
  
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Well done! You were able to guess the "
                + "correct number in under 10 tries");
            System.out.print("You guessed: ");

            for ( int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
            {
               System.out.print(guesses[i] + " ");
            }


           System.out.println("The random number generated was "
             + number + ", it only took you " + tries + " tries.");

          }
  
      System.out.println("");

      System.out.print("Do you wish to try again with a different "
         + "number? (Enter y or n ): ");
      again = input.next();

      System.out.println("");
      }
   }
  
/*
METHOD 1
Description
  
A method that generates the random number to be guessed returns the
random number to main. Two parameters are the two numbers needed to generate
the random number (1 and 100 in this case).
  

*/
public static int GetRandomNumber (int rangeLow, int rangeHigh)
{

   Random gen = new Random();
   int number;

   number = gen.nextInt(rangeHigh) + rangeLow;

   return number;
}

/*

METHOD 2
This method tells the user if the guess is too low or too high. It will have
2 parameters one for the random number and the second is the user guess.

*/
public static void LowOrHigh (int number, int userGuess )
{
   if (userGuess > number )
   {
      System.out.println("The value that you guessed is too high, "
      +"Try guessing a lower number. ");
      System.out.println("");
   }
  
   else if (userGuess < number )
   {
      System.out.println("The value that you guessed is too low, "
      +"Try guessing a higher number. ");
      System.out.println("");
   }
}

/*

METHOD 3
This method will get the user guess. It has 2 parameters which will be the
valid range the user should guess between (in this case 1 and 100). It will
return the users guess as an integer. This method should validate that the
users guess is between the two parameters.
*/
public static int GetUserGuess(int rangeLow, int rangeHigh)

{
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int userGuess;
  
   System.out.print("Enter a number between " + rangeLow + " and " + rangeHigh + ": ");
   userGuess = scan.nextInt();
  
   while (userGuess > rangeHigh || userGuess < rangeLow)
   {
      System.out.println("The number given was not within the range, Try again ");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.print("Enter a number between " + rangeLow + " and " + rangeHigh + ": ");
      userGuess = scan.nextInt();
   }

   return userGuess;
}
  
}
```

I'm sorry if its obvious im still pretty new to programming.

Comment: At a glance I can't see an obvious issue. Can you please show an example of some numbers you input and what was printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you store a guess, you always store it in `guesses[tries]`, and then immediately afterwards, you increment `tries`. Your while condition then checks if tries is less than `guess.length - 1`.

More generally, to program you need to know how to debug. Debugging is generally the act of following along with the code and checking what it actually does vs. what you wanted it to do. You can use a debugger for this, alternatively, you can add a boatload of System.out statements to follow along.

Do that, and you'll find the error in your logic. I've already given you quite a sizable hint in the first paragraph ;)